# Proper way to initialize a vector of unique pointers in C++14

Tags: c++, vector, c++14, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

For initializing a vector of unique pointers in C++14, I can consider the following two ways. Which method is better?

```
#include<memory>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main(){

  const int N = 10000000;

  {//first method
    vector<unique_ptr<int>> vec(N);
    for(auto it=vec.begin(); it!=vec.end();++it){
      auto ptr = make_unique<int>();
      *it = std::move(ptr);
    }
  }

  {//second method
    vector<unique_ptr<int>> vec;
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
      vec.push_back(make_unique<int>());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I would use the second + reserve call

Comment: In the first method, you can use for(auto &it : vec)

Comment: Barring ultra-smart compilers, the second alternative will involve frequent reallocation of the vector as it grows. You can avoid this by reserving space beforehand. As for `push_back` vs `emplace_back`, [gcc produces identical code in both cases](https://godbolt.org/g/4VmWGV).

Comment: Are you sure that’s C++11? The `make_unique` function [wasn’t standardized until C++14](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique).

Comment: @DanielH edited it. I'm a beginner, sorry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Either way works.  The second is marginally more efficient *if* you reserve the correct capacity first.  Personally, I think the standard algorithms are more expressive.  I would do it like this:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> vec;
vec.reserve(N);
std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(vec), N, [] { return std::make_unique<int>(); });
```

Comment: `push_back` can only be less efficient because of the checks of capacity and incrementing the size for each element.

Comment: Perhaps.  We'd have to measure to be sure.  Using the first method, we have to 0 fill 40 million bytes of memory, and I suspect this will outweigh the additional computational complexity in the second method.

Comment: The performance difference is [extremely marginal](http://quick-bench.com/gpOyhwvMfHKVY5Up4hBs1Trn-vI) at best. At least in that benchmark configuration.